# Monitor / sniff network traffic for a non-root user

Tags: git, https, github

Is there any way to monitor network traffic for all processes owned by a non-root user?

Specifically creating developer tools to see when a user pushes to a git remote.

Comment: You should be able to track this from Git if you're using the enterprise git.

Comment: @Robby1212 tell me more - my agent thing may or may not have access to their github etc - but I may wish to do it without having access to their github account.

Comment: Yup found it, audit log, https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-enterprise-account/viewing-the-audit-logs-for-organizations-in-your-enterprise-account